# Rails: fields_for not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I was following this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) about `Nested Model Form`, but something seems weird.

Here is `Model` relationship

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
end

class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end
```

**_form.html.erb**(created by `scaffold`)

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %> 
  </div>
   <% f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
    <div class ='question'>
      <%= builder.label :content, "Question" %>
      <br>
      <%= builder.text_area :content, :rows => 3 %> 
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**survey_controller.rb**

```
# GET /surveys/new
  def new
    @survey = Survey.new

    3.times do |i|
      @survey.questions.build
    end
  end
```

I was expecting it will display like

[image]

However,it didn't display 3 blocks of question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've missed a very small but important part of the form - actually *outputting* the `f.fields_for` call.

You need to call `<%= f.fields_for :question` (note the `=`) to actually output the generated form.

Comment: Oh god, how I miss this! Thanks, I was stuck on it for a while.

Comment: It took me 3 days to work this out when I was starting out

Comment: Oh dear god, I've been doing Rails for 2 years now and this still happens to me! UGH! This may sound sarcastic, but it's not: Thank you for pointing out the obvious.